# Need info on parsing the string output and converting it to key value pair

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am executing a command on linux and getting this as a output in python,it is a string.

---

```
Product Name    version  Appliance Model  
============    =======  ===============  
ACD LINUX 1234   1.0      5550
```

---

Where product Name is `"ACD Linux 1234"`
version is `1.0`
Applicance mode is `5550`....respectively for remaining columns.

I wanted to some thing like to create a key value pair for each items..
Example :

```
"productname:ACD Linux 1234",version:1.0,"Appliance mode":5550
```

I need help on how to construct key,value pair out of above string output.I am facing issue like below.

```
1.Not able to split based on spaces.

2.No able to split based on "=" character.
```

Can any body help me on this ?

Comment: isnt the data position based? Can you give us examples of few more rows? It looks like you can read the file position based and then use key and value to get the key value pair. If these are the only two lines, then the code is easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can split based on new line character,and put into dictionary based on position

```
'''
Let a string s1 be

Product Name   version  Appliance Model  
============   =======  ===============  
ACD LINUX 1234   1.0      5550 
'''
l1=s1.split('\n')

d=dict(zip(l1[0].split('  '),l1[2].split('  '))
```

You may have to check for number of whitespaces in input string for proper parsing